# this form gives me an error "FAILED TO SEND"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The code of the contact form below gives me an error `FORM SENDING FAILED`.
Can you please help me resolve the issue?The code of the contact form below gives me an error `FORM SENDING FAILED`.
Can you please help me resolve the issue?The code of the contact form below gives me an error `FORM SENDING FAILED`.
Can you please help me resolve the issue?

```
    <form id="contactform" method="post" action="$_SELF">
        <label class="hide" for="author">Full Name</label> 
        <input class="input-fields" id="author" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" required autofocus />

        <label class="hide" for="email">Email</label> 
        <input class="input-fields" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="" autofocus />

        <label class="hide" for="email">Mobile No</label> 
        <input class="input-fields" id="email" name="phone_no" type="text" placeholder="Mobile No" value="" autofocus />

        <label class="hide" for="author">Company</label> 
        <input class="input-fields" id="author" name="company" type="text" placeholder="Company" value="" required autofocus />

        <label class="hide" for="select_category">Select a Industry:</label> 
        <span id="select_group" class="select-group">
            <select name="vehicle">
                <option value="General" >Select a Industry:</option>
                <option value="General" >Health Centres Hospitals</option>
                <option value="Sales" >Tradeshows Conferences</option>
                <option value="Support" >Fast Foods and Restaurants</option>
                <option value="Support" >Night CLub, Bars and Disos</option>
                <option value="Support" >Banks , Rent Estate</option>
                <option value="Support" >Educational Institute</option>
                <option value="Support" >Recreational Facilities</option>
                <option value="Support" >Malls,Luxury Retail and Store Windows</option>
            </select>
        </span>

        <label class="hide" for="subject_title">Solutions</label> 
        <input class="input-fields" id="subject_title" name="solution" type="text" placeholder="Solutions" value="" autofocus />

        <label class="hide" for="author">Require</label> 
        <input class="input-fields" id="author" name="require" type="text" placeholder="Require" value="" required autofocus />

        <label class="hide" for="comment">Message</label> 
        <textarea id="comment" class="input-fields" placeholder="Message" name="message" cols="40" rows="200"></textarea>
        <span class="form_response">
                                           <ul id="errors" class="">
                                                    <li id="info">There were some problems with your form submission:</li>
                                           </ul>
                                                <p id="success" class="">Thanks for your message! We will get back to you ASAP!</p>
                                    </span>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit-contact-info" class="contact-info-submit form-submit-button span2" value="Send message">
                </form>
                          </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </main>
  </div>


 <?php
         //If the form is submitted
        echo "hello";
           if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) 
           {
             $message = $_POST['message'];
           }                                     
                   //Check to make sure that the exit date field is not empty
             if(trim($_POST['vehicle']) == '') {
               $hasError = true;
             } else {
               $vehicle = trim($_POST['vehicle']);
             }
         //Check to make sure that the exit date field is not empty
             if(trim($_POST['require']) == '') {
               $hasError = true;
             } else {
               $require = trim($_POST['require']);
             }
         //Check to make sure that the exit date field is not empty
             if(trim($_POST['solution']) == '') {
               $hasError = true;
             } else {
               $solution = trim($_POST['solution']);
             }

           //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
             if(trim($_POST['name']) == '') {
               $hasError = true;
             } else {
               $name = trim($_POST['name']);
             }

           //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
             if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
               $hasError = true;
             } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
               $hasError = true;
             } else {
               $email = trim($_POST['email']);
             }
           //Check to make sure that the mobile no field is not empty
             if(trim($_POST['phone_no']) == '') {
               $hasError = true;
             } else {
               $phone_no = trim($_POST['phone_no']);
             }

             //If there is no error, send the email
    if(!isset($hasError)) 
      {
               $emailTo = "sahil7771@gmail.com"; //Put your own email address here
               $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMobile No: $phone_no \n\n Your Industry: $vehicle \n\
              \n\n Your Requirement: $require \n\n Your Solution: $solution \n\n 
              \n\n Message : $message 
              \n\nPlease Contact $name  on $phone_no\n \n /====================================/ ";
               $headers = 'From: Touch Active  <'. $emailTo .'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email; 


                                              if(mail($emailTo, 'Mail From Touch Active', $body, $headers))
                                              { //Replace Your Website Subject
                                                $response=1;
                                                $emailSent = true; 


                                              ?> 

               <div id="responsive-container" ><p>Thanks For Messaging Us You Will Shortly Expect Our Assistance ( With In 24hrs ).</p></div>

               <?php
               }
                else
               {
                 ?>
                 <div id="page-title"><h2>Failed To Sent</h2></div>
                 <?php
                 $response=0;
               }
         }

   ?>
```

Comment: Do you get `Failed To Sent`, or `FORM SENDING FAILED`? Because it seems you could get the first one, and in your question you said it was the second one. Which is it?

Comment: What this line mean ? `$sent =  mail($emailTo, 'Mail From Touch Active', $body, $headers )
    { //Replace Your Website Subject`

Comment: Actually the message which i dispalying in the question .. it gives that error  <div id="page-title"><h2>Failed To Sent</h2></div>

Comment: sorie i put the code lil bit wrong ... please check it once again

Answer (score 1):

Change in form `action="$_SELF"` to `action="$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']"`, because there isn't constant like `$_SELF`.

Comment: their is not any problem in ACTION as i already checked it  .. STILL THANKS ALOT

Answer (score 0):

Actually its working here with no errors
try it with this little script, to check or e-mail is permitted :

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

I have tested your script with minor adjustment:

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="#">
        <label class="hide" for="author">Full Name</label> 
        <input class="input-fields" id="author" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="aaa" required autofocus />

        <label class="hide" for="email">Email</label> 
        <input class="input-fields" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="xxx@boboba.com" autofocus />

        <label class="hide" for="email">Mobile No</label> 
        <input class="input-fields" id="email" name="phone_no" type="text" placeholder="Mobile No" value="0322233355" autofocus />

        <label class="hide" for="author">Company</label> 
        <input class="input-fields" id="author" name="company" type="text" placeholder="Company" value="aaa" required autofocus />

        <label class="hide" for="select_category">Select a Industry:</label> 
        <span id="select_group" class="select-group">
            <select name="vehicle">
                <option value="General" >Select a Industry:</option>
                <option value="General" >Health Centres Hospitals</option>
                <option value="Sales" >Tradeshows Conferences</option>
                <option value="Support" >Fast Foods and Restaurants</option>
                <option value="Support" >Night CLub, Bars and Disos</option>
                <option value="Support" >Banks , Rent Estate</option>
                <option value="Support" >Educational Institute</option>
                <option value="Support" >Recreational Facilities</option>
                <option value="Support" >Malls,Luxury Retail and Store Windows</option>
            </select>
        </span>

        <label class="hide" for="subject_title">Solutions</label> 
        <input class="input-fields" id="subject_title" name="solution" type="text" placeholder="Solutions" value="aaa" autofocus />

        <label class="hide" for="author">Require</label> 
        <input class="input-fields" id="author" name="require" type="text" placeholder="Require" value="aaa" required autofocus />

        <label class="hide" for="comment">Message</label> 
        <textarea id="comment" class="input-fields" placeholder="Message" name="message" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>
        <span class="form_response">
                                           <ul id="errors" class="">
                                                    <li id="info">There were some problems with your form submission:</li>
                                           </ul>
                                                <p id="success" class="">Thanks for your message! We will get back to you ASAP!</p>
                                    </span>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit-contact-info" class="contact-info-submit form-submit-button span2" value="Send message">
                </form>
                          </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </main>
  </div>


 <?php
         //If the form is submitted

           if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) 
           {
             $message = $_POST['message'];
           }                                     
                   //Check to make sure that the exit date field is not empty
             if(trim($_POST['vehicle']) == '') {
               $hasError = "1";
             } else {
               $vehicle = trim($_POST['vehicle']);
             }
         //Check to make sure that the exit date field is not empty
             if(trim($_POST['require']) == '') {
               $hasError = "2";
             } else {
               $require = trim($_POST['require']);
             }
         //Check to make sure that the exit date field is not empty
             if(trim($_POST['solution']) == '') {
               $hasError = "3";
             } else {
               $solution = trim($_POST['solution']);
             }

           //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
             if(trim($_POST['name']) == '') {
               $hasError = "4";
             } else {
               $name = trim($_POST['name']);
             }

           //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
             if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
               $hasError = "5";
             } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
               $hasError = "6";
             } else {
               $email = trim($_POST['email']);
             }
           //Check to make sure that the mobile no field is not empty
             if(trim($_POST['phone_no']) == '') {
               $hasError = "7";
             } else {
               $phone_no = trim($_POST['phone_no']);
             }

             //If there is no error, send the email
    if(!isset($hasError)) 
      {
      echo "OK";
               $emailTo = "sahil7771@gmail.com"; //Put your own email address here
               $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMobile No: $phone_no \n\n Your Industry: $vehicle \n\
              \n\n Your Requirement: $require \n\n Your Solution: $solution \n\n 
              \n\n Message : $message 
              \n\nPlease Contact $name  on $phone_no\n \n /====================================/ ";
               $headers = 'From: Touch Active  <'. $emailTo .'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email; 


                                              if(mail($emailTo, 'Mail From Touch Active', $body, $headers))
                                              { //Replace Your Website Subject
                                                $response=1;
                                                $emailSent = true; 


                                              ?> 

               <div id="responsive-container" ><p>Thanks For Messaging Us You Will Shortly Expect Our Assistance ( With In 24hrs ).</p></div>

               <?php
               }
                else
               {
                 ?>
                 <div id="page-title"><h2>Failed To Sent</h2></div>
                 <?php echo "NOK";
                 echo $hasError;
                 echo $response;
                 $response=0;
               }
         }
         else{
         echo $hasError;
         }

   ?>
```

Comment: If you need a more secure e-mail script, grab it here: http://wistudat.be/contact/index.php?lang=en 
You can modify it to your needs